# MongoDB - Manipulating multi-level arrays in a document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am currently building an app with Meteor and MongoDB. I have a 3 level document structure with array in array:

```
{
  _id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
  description: "Some title",
  categories: [{
    id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
    name: "Foo",
    options: [{
      id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
      name: "bar",
      likes: ["abc", "bce"]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Now, the document could be manipulated at any level. Means:

1. `description` could be changed
2. categories can be added / removed / renamed
3. options can be added / removed / renamed
4. users can like options, so they must be added or removed

1 and 2 is quite easy. It is also relatively easy to add or remove a new option:

```
MyCollection.update({ _id: id, "categories.id": categoryId }, {
  $push: {
    "categories.$.options": {
      id: Random.id
      name: optionName
    }
  }
});
```

But manipulating the `options` hash requires to do that on javascript objects. That means I first need to find my document, iterate over the options and then write them back.

At least that's what I am doing right now. But I don't like that approach.

What I was thinking about is splitting the collection, at least to put the likes into it's own collection referencing the origin document.

Or is there another way? I don't really like both of my possible solutions.

Comment: Another idea just coming up: instead of categories / options beeing an array it could make sense to use an object with the id as key instead of a value of the corresponding object.

Comment: IMO you'd be better off refactoring your collections *if your concern is the complexity of manipulating the sub-array*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of query one would normally use a the Mongo [position](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator. Although from the docs.

> Nested Arrays
>
> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries
>   which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse
>   arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $
>   placeholder is a single value

Thus the only way to natively do what you want is by using specific indexes.

```
db.test.update({},{$pull:{"categories.0.options.0.likes":"abc"}})
```

Unfortunately Mongo does not allow to easily get the index of a match nested document.

I would normally say that once your queries become that difficult it's probably a good idea to revisit the way you store data. Also with that many arrays to which you will be pushing data, Mongo will probably be relocating a lot of documents. This is definitely something that you want to minimize.

So at this point you will need to separate your data out into different documents and even collections.

Your first documents would look like this:

```
{
  _id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
  description: "Some title",
  categories: [{
    id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
    name: "Foo",
    options: ["shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR"]
  }]
}
```

This way you can easily add/remove options as you mentioned in your question. You would then need a second collection with documents that represent each option.

```
{
  _id: "shtZFiTeHrPKyJ8vR",
  name: "bar",
  likes: ["abc", "bce"]
}
```

You can learn more about references [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/). This is similar to what you mentioned in your comment. The benefit of this is that you are already reducing the potential amount of relocation. Depending on how you use your data you may even be reducing network usage.

Now doing updates on the likes is easy.

```
MyCollection.update({ _id: id}, {
  $push: {likes: "value"}
});
```

This does, however, require you to make two queries to the db. Although on the flip side you do a lot less on the client side and a lot less bandwidth is used.

Some other questions you need to ask yourself is if that depth of nesting is really needed. There might be an easier way to go about achieving your goal that doesn't require it to become so complicated.

Comment: Thanks - I think I can work with that. Your approach makes sense. Now I need to dive deeper and prove whether I can just use this structure or what makes sense. 
Is there any special reason you referenced the option from the category and not vise versa? I rather would have put the categoryId into the option document.

Comment: No special reason. The way you end up doing the referencing. Option -> Category or Category -> Option will solely depend on how you intend to use the data. Essentially figure out what your data flow is. ie do you want to look up options based on categories or the other way around.